# Is there a composer who made a fusion between Latin and Bebop Jazz?

Tags: genre, jazz

I'm lately really into Bebop music, like Art Blakey and The Jazz Messengers and also Tecno Brega, really low-profile dance music from Brazil. I was wondering if there is like a fusion of these 2 genres (rythmic Jazz and Latin music), or someone who tried to mash these together.
Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a list question.

Comment: This question could pretty easily be adapted to something like "which jazz artists pioneered the fusion between Latin and Bebop", which is not without merit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a rich tradition of musical exchange between "latin" and jazz, going back to Jelly Roll Morton, who talked about "The Spanish Tinge." Today, the phrase is more often stated as the "latin tinge," which ethnomusicologist John Storm Roberts used as the title of [a book on the subject](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0195121015).

Your question asks about Brazilian music, which generally isn't a major component of the music people talk about when they talk about "latin jazz." You might instead look for references to "bossa nova," which blends samba and jazz (although not particularly bebop jazz). Brazilian guitarist João Gilberto is often [credited with inventing bossa nova](http://daniellathompson.com/Texts/Brazzil/Plain_Joao.htm), although I'm skeptical of any story that puts the credit on one person. Pianist/composer Antonio Carlos "Tom" Jobim was also a critical pioneer who composed many of the standards.

The most popular American musicians working in this mix were Stan Getz and Charlie Byrd, but again, this is a very rich vein. It would be a shame to stop at them, but I don't want this to be merely a list answer.

America definitely had a fascination with Cuban culture at the same time that bebop music was becoming prominent, so there is a lot of music which blends components of both. Dizzy Gillespie is the most prominent musician identified with the intersection of the two fields. Again, we don't want this site to be filled with mere lists, so I'll point you to the Wikipedia page on ["latin jazz"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_jazz).

Answer (score 0):

John Birks 'Dizzy' Gillespie is also a 'father of Bebop' together with Charlie 'Yardbird' or 'Bird' Parker; or more simply, Bird. Please find New Faces lp/cassette/cd? which from 1984 features Branford Marsalis/multi-reed artist. New Faces is focused on Dizzy Gillespie and friends, hence the apt title: New Faces. There are/is one or more latin pieces very much in a jazz/bebop genre, and it is a great album.